# GCM downstream message missing values inserted by my server

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging, intentservice

I'm trying to respond to a device with some basic info once it registers with my server, but the response from my server seems to be empty. Below at the line where I assign command = extras.getString("command"), command is null. Also when I break at that line and check the contents of extras in the debugger the bundle contains no extras at all.

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    if (extras != null && !extras.isEmpty()) { 

            // This line returns null
            String command = extras.getString("command");
```

Relevant code from server:

```
...

jMessage message = new jMessage();
Map<String, String> responseData = new HashMap<String, String>();
//these are the values I want to read on device, but they are missing
responseData.put("command", "REGISTRATION_SUCCESSFUL");
responseData.put("userID", userID.toString());

message.setmTo(reg_id);
message.setmMessageId(nextMessageId());
message.setmData(responseData);

sendDownstreamMessage(message);

...
```

.

```
public void sendDownstreamMessage(jMessage m) throws NotConnectedException{

    String json = createJsonMessageFromMessage(m);
    Packet request = new GcmPacketExtension(json).toPacket();
    connection.sendPacket(request);
}

public static String createJsonMessage(String to, String messageId,
                                       Map<String, String> payload, String collapseKey, Long timeToLive,
                                       Boolean delayWhileIdle) {
    Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    message.put("to", to);
    if (collapseKey != null) {
        message.put("collapse_key", collapseKey);
    }
    if (timeToLive != null) {
        message.put("time_to_live", timeToLive);
    }
    if (delayWhileIdle != null && delayWhileIdle) {
        message.put("delay_while_idle", true);
    }
    message.put("message_id", messageId);
    message.put("data", payload);
    return JSONValue.toJSONString(message);
}


public static String createJsonMessageFromMessage(jMessage m){

    return createJsonMessage(m.getmRecipients(), m.getmMessageId(), m.getmData(), m.getmCollapeKey(),
            m.getmTimeToLive(), m.getmDelayWhileIdle());

}
```

Message sent by my server according to smack debug console. Note that the data still appears to be there: (line breaks added by me)

```
<message id='Yi0UJ-4'>
    <gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">
    {"data":
        {"userID":"187188880",
        "command":"REGISTRATION_SUCCESSFUL"},
    "message_id":"m-b7b64e2f-ab89-4e1d-9764-b562f2133ee9",
    "to":"(GCM reg id, edited out)"}
    </gcm>
</message>
```

The keys available in the response from my server on the device. Note that the userID and command fields are now missing:

```
I/EXTRA KEY SET﹕ KEY: message_type
I/EXTRA KEY SET﹕ KEY: event
I/EXTRA KEY SET﹕ KEY: google.message_id
I/EXTRA KEY SET﹕ KEY: android.support.content.wakelockid
```

I'm beginning to wonder if server is actually sending the amp codes in the response and it isn't just a display error. I don't get a nack from google so I assumed it was fine, but maybe the GCM servers can handle it but the Google Play library can't? If that's the case, why is the Smack library adding amp codes some times but not others. For example, in the response there are quotes in the gcm tag.

Comment: Can you do a `Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());` before your `String command = extras.getString("command");` So that you can find out what are inside your `extras`.

Comment: @ztan the bundle from the intent that's passed to my intentservice: `Bundle[{message_type=send_event, event=sent, google.message_id=6034952991868517005, android.support.content.wakelockid=1}]`, and the message from the Smack debug console:  `...{&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;userID&quot;:&quot;2106038418&quot;,&quot;command&quot;:&quot;REGISTRATION_SUCCESSFUL&quot;}...`

Comment: still little hard to see the result, can you log the  `extras.keySet()`  too?

Comment: @ztan updated main post with contents of extras from logcat

Comment: From the `keySet()` shown in the Logcat, it shows `message_type`. All you need to do in the `onHandleIntent()` is to check the `message_type`, so I dont think you need to check the `command`. You can read the official documentation about `onHandleIntent()` https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#sample-send or this tutorial about XMPP: http://javapapers.com/android/android-chat-with-google-gcm-xmpp/

Comment: In the second link they put data in the message to the device using the optional data field in the message using key value pairs `payload.put("SM", "ECHO: " + clientMessage);`, then on the device they are calling `if("USERLIST".equals(extras.get("SM")))`. This what I'm trying to accomplish. I can see that when I send the packet from my server it has the data field with some key:value pairs in it, but when it arrives on my device there doesn't appear to be any data,